# Create a new column with intervals in R

Tags: r, loops, time, tidyverse, intervals

I am looking for a quick solution how to create a new column in a data frame (`interval`) by taking into account the output of the `time` column.

###### My dummy column

```
   time <- c(7.1,8.2,9.3,10.4,11.5,12.6,50.9) 
   df <-  data.frame(time)
   df
```

###### My desired output

[image]

Based on the info in the TIME column, I would like to determine the interval. In my example, whatever comes between 0.0-10.0 (including 10) equals interval 10. The intervals are grouped by 10, as you see. So whatever comes between 10.0-20.0 will be assigned to interval 20 and so on and so forth.

Any hints on how to get the new column with intervals would be highly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: something like `(time %/% 10 + 1) * 10`

Comment: I think that is exactly what I want. I used ```df["interval"]<-(df$time %/% 10 + 1) * 10``` to get the new column into my data.frame. Many thanks. Just one last thing. Could you explain what you did there so that I can understand it better? Much appreciated.

Comment: I arrived to the same conclusion. It is about figuring out across how many whole intervals the value time covers (hence `%/%` i.e. integer-division) is useful, and then you want the right-end of said interval, and that's `+ 1`. Also, all of your intervals have the same length, `10`.

Comment: @Mossa is correct. Integer division by 10 as this is the interval you are looking for. Add 1 and multiply by 10 to get the results. Modulo and integer division are handy shortcuts to know.

Answer (score 0):

Moved comments to an answer. You can use integer division to do this. You divide the time column by 10 as this is the interval you are looking for. Add 1 and multiply by 10 to get the results.

```
df["interval"]<-(df$time %/% 10 + 1) * 10
```